# のに being used in a positive sense?

Tags: grammar

I read an example sentence with the word 検索

> 索引があるので**検索**するのに便利だ

I know のに can show disappointment. Here, however, I think it's being used in a positive sense?

> Because index(es) exist(s), searching up (things) is convenient/easy.

But how is this のに used here?

Comment: No, のに here is different from what you are thinking. It is simply a nominalizer particle の + particle に.

Comment: @JimmyYang Actually the other のに is also "nominalizer particle の + particle に".

Comment: @EddieKal I don't get it?

Comment: @JimmyYang See my answer.

Comment: That's what I said?

Comment: @JimmyYang What I'm saying is **both are** "nominalizer particle の + particle に", so it's not like that one isn't and this one is, which is what your first comment seems to suggest.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not the particle のに meaning "even though", "despite", which is composed of 準体助詞「の」＋接続助詞「に」([デジタル大辞泉（小学館）](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E3%81%AE%E3%81%AB/))

This is 準体助詞「の」＋**格助詞**「に」. (ibid.) The difference is significant, because with a 格助詞 (case particle) what this のに does is first turn the preceding phrase into a noun and semantically connect it with what follows. に being a 格助詞 signifies the semantic relation between the verb phrase(or adjective phrase)-turned-noun and the following phrase.

This happens to parallel how certain prepositions work in English.

> *The tool is convenient for do searches (ungrammatical)

So turn the part after the preposition "for" into a gerund and we get

> The tool is convenient for doing searches

voila!

> [検索するの]に便利だ

This means: "convenient for doing searches"

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Never knew things like 接続助詞 and 格助詞 existed!

Comment: Is it possible to say 検索に便利だ - convenient for searches - instead?

Comment: @YaroslavFyodorov Syntactically it seems fine, but I don't think it's used very commonly. I can't pinpoint why. But some other similar constructs are very common: 通勤に便利だ